# Marking veins using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I was trying to figure out a way to mark the veins in an image using OpenCV in Python. Most of the similar articles i came across uses CLAHE to produce a result,I did CLAHE multiple times on grayscale image, and it did make the veins more viewable but i cant figure out a way to mark the vein in a different color. CLAHE also significantly reduces the overall image quality.

My input image:

[image: img]

After CLAHE 4 times:

[image: img]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def multi_clahe(img, num):
    for i in xrange(num):
        img = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(4+i*2,4+i*2)).apply(img)
    return img

img = cv2.imread('img.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

final = multi_clahe(gray, 4)

cv2.imwrite('image.png',final)
cv2.imshow('image',final)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: First convert the image to hsv and seperate out the skin region. Then it becomes relatively easy to mark the veins. Also if there is a possibility to set an ROI on the image to find the veins, the problem is a piece of cake.

Comment: you mean manually setting ROI ?

Comment: i cant do that. i want my code to be generic.
that was just a test image. :/

Comment: Ok, add your code, i'll see what can be done for better

Comment: its basic, but.. did anyways..

Comment: using a better imaging setup would help. crap in == crap out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the method to follow-

- Veins cant be found outside hand. So remove the nonsense by converting image to hsv and cv2.inRange() with low, high skin values. Make a track bar if you cant figure out proper values.

[image: This]

- Your skin is smoother compared to the folds on the hand holding it. Use Canny edge with proper parameters, dilate a little and filter out the high frequency portion by and'ing.

[image]

- CLAHE
- Adaptive Threshold
- Morphological and noise removal operations.

Suggestion to improve the output:

1. Get a better image setting, with only arm ideally.
2. Figure out proper parameters for CLAHE, Thresholding,Canny

[image]

Comment: did you use OpenCV-Python ?

Comment: yeah, but used the same python file for another question. Try out the steps i told in order and feel free to ask here in the comments if you have an error.

Comment: sure.. will do (Y)