# How to extract the finger vein clearly from camera or picture by using opencv

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I'm using Opencv extract the finger vein from a camera, first I use the GaussianBlur to smooth the image and then use the adpateThreshold to get the binary image, but the result isn't good, because the camera has a lot of salt noise and it made each frame are difference(for the brightness), the binary image is very unstable(I also tried the medianBlur but the result isn't good too), so I think to extract the vein from camera can't simply use the threshold method. could anyone give me some suggestion about how to extract a clear and stable finger vein by using opencv?
thanks a lot.

[Photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGL7N.png)

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188667/marking-veins-using-opencv)

Comment: I've seen some articles using Gabor filter to extract veins from images similar to yours. I let you check this article that describe a full method: "Yang, Jinfeng, & Yang, Jinli. (2009). Multi-Channel Gabor Filter Design for Finger-Vein Image Enhancement. Image and Graphics, 2009. ICIG '09. Fifth International Conference on, 87-91."